# ssllabs keeps saying sslv3 enabled when it isn't

Tags: nginx, ssl

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=cablework.co

I can't figure out why it keeps saying "C". I have disabled SSLv3.

this is my config file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    server_name cablework.co;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cablework.co.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
    return 301 https://www.cablework.co$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cablework.co.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    ssl_ciphers 'AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.4.4 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 10s;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/www.cablework.co-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=63072000;
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    root /home/kryptonit3/cablework/public;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name www.cablework.co;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to specify `ssl_protocols` and `ssl_ciphers` for your `server` named `cablework.co`. So the defaults - whatever they are - get used.

Comment: the whole point of the first `server` is to redirect to `https://www`, so is the ssl site pulling from the first `server` directive?

Comment: Of course it is. That's what is in the `server_name`!

Comment: do you have any recommendations or do i need to clone the second server content with the first one?

Comment: Ideally you should `include` them from a common file, especially if you run a lot of SSL sites.